# Why do I have to make a seperate variable to correct this loop? (Javascript Basics)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, counter

I am currently learning Javascript so I will try my best with my choice of words.

In the following code below.
I want the variable "***allFoods***" to display all the different variations.

Although, I have found a loophole, I like to understand the logic and why things are done rather than memorizing code.

```
>1 var fruits = ["apples", "pears"]; 
>2 var junk = ["twinkies", "pizza"];
>3 var allFoods = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < junk.length; j++) {
      allFoods = fruits[i] + junk[i];
        alert(allFoods);
```

Instead, of the variable "allFoods" returning all the different variations.. 
applestwinkies, applespizza, pearstwinkies, pearspizza

It returns this...
applestwinkies, applestwinkies, pearspizza, pears,pizza

**The loophole i found is**...

```
     >1 var fruits = ["apples", "pears"]; 
     >2 var junk = ["twinkies", "pizza"];
     >3 var allFoods = [];
     >4 var b = 0;
     >5 for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
     >6   for (var j = 0; j < junk.length; j++) {
     >7      allFoods[b] = fruits[i] + junk[i];
             b++;
     >8        alert(allFoods);
```

Although it is working. I have no idea what is going on and why it's working!

Comment: [`fruits.forEach(function(fruit) { junk.forEach(function(junk) { allFoods.push(fruit + junk); }); });`](http://jsbin.com/celutuxiju/1/)

Comment: Please format your code properly. For starters, remove all the line numbers before uploading your code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```
  allFoods = fruits[i] + junk[i];
```

Change it to:

```
  allFoods = fruits[i] + junk[j];
                              ^ use index j here
```

Comment: Wow... Using the "J" index where it is supposed to be worked for me using the "allFoods.push()" function. This is fine, as now I know what the program is doing and why... BUT.. Why will it still not work with all the correct indexes using a simple allFoods = fruits[i] + junk[j];

Comment: @Mike: That's probably due the fact that you're not *adding* any elements to the `allFoods` array, you're assigning each result in turn to the same variable. @Thriggle's answer addresses that part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding elements to an array, you can do it multiple ways.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("One"); // Pushes a new element into the array
arr[1] = "Two"; // Sets a specific element in the array
// arr === ["One","Two"]
```

The plus operator `+` provides different functionality depending on the context. When used with string values, it will concatenate the strings together. Thus `allFoods = fruits[1] + junk[1];` is equivalent to `allFoods = "pearspizza";`

What you'd want to do is loop through the arrays individually and use the `push` method to append elements to the new array, as in the following code example:

```js
var fruits = ["apples", "pears"];
var junk = ["twinkies", "pizza"];
var allFoods = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  allFoods.push(fruits[i]);
}
for (var j = 0; j < junk.length; j++) {
  allFoods.push(junk[j]);
}
alert(allFoods);
```

Of course, you could also use the [Array object's `concat()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to join two arrays into one.

```js
var fruits = ["apples", "pears"];
var junk = ["twinkies", "pizza"];
var allFoods = fruits.concat(junk);
alert(allFoods);
```